# JOIN 2 tables ORDER BY SUM value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: 1st is comment, 2nd is rating

```
SELECT * FROM comment_table a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT comment_id, SUM(rating_value) AS total_rating FROM rating_table GROUP BY comment_id) b
ON a.comment_id = b.comment_id 
ORDER BY b.total_rating DESC
```

I tried the above SQL but doesn't work!
Object is to display a list of comments order by rating points of each comments.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags. (And provide same data etc).

Comment: Looking at your current query it should work as expected for both SQL Server & MySQL. Show some sample data and exactly what is your expected output and what are you currently getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.* FROM (    
    SELECT * FROM comment_table a 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT comment_id, SUM(rating_value) AS total_rating FROM rating_table GROUP BY comment_id) b
    ON a.comment_id = b.comment_id
) AS s
ORDER BY s.total_rating DESC
```

Nest it inside an another select. It will then output the data in the correct order.